# Has anyone use the MailChimp API V3.0 to create the List

Tags: mailchimp

I want to use MailChimp API V3.0 to create the list through c#. Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

you can use cUrl with C#. For API call please take a look at:
[enter link description here](http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/lists/)

If you want to play with your account and see what happen, use the playground tool. It's great and you will see how the requests are done!
[enter link description here](https://us2.api.mailchimp.com/playground/)